# Distributing multiple versions of the same App

Tags: ios, app-store

My customer is a software house and wants to have an iOs App to consume data and methods of already existing data-driven systems (that they develop), and set this goal for distribution:

- The companies that use this System have different versions (client A uses the old v5.3, client B uses v7.0, ...). My customer wants to be able to control the App version available for each client, making sure they use the one that's compatible with the system's version they are using (in terms of features, ...).

How should I tackle this?
I have only used the standard Developer Program, so far, publishing Apps on the AppStore...
Is the "iOS Developer Enterprise Program" suitable for this?

Can I have different versions of the same App (and prevent them to automatically update) in order to have 1 App version for 1 System version, or do I need to develop different Apps (different identifications) for each System version?

Answer (score 0):

With the "iOS Developer Enterprise Program" you can distribute inHouse versions of your apps so you don't need to publish on the AppStore. They can install them from a simple ftp so you can choose the version you want to provide for each client.